# Memory Cache GetData Returns Null

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api, memorycache

I am using WebAPI Memory Cache to cache my list. 
Structure of my list object is like:

```
[Serializable]
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Entity> ChildEntites {get;set;}
}

var entities = new List<Entity>
{
    new Entity
    {
        Id = new Guid("644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b"),
        Desc = "desc",
        ChildEntities = new List<Entity>
        {
            Id = new Guid("644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b78d-ed78c3f92c2b"),
            Desc = "desc2",
            ChildEntities = null
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing

```
cache.SetData<IEnumerable<Entity>>("key", entities);
```

and

```
cache.GetData<IEnumerable<Entity>>("key");
```

but GetData is always returning me null.

Initially I thought it might be Guids which could be causing the problem but then I tried to cache a Guid and it got cached.

Can anyone let me know why this could be happening ?

Could it be because of my submodel which is of same class type ?

Comment: How are you setting up the cache? Please show the code.

Comment: Actually I am getting an exception while Serializing entities to binary stream. 
Serializable attribute missing exception....

Comment: I have serializable atrribute on my class Entity but I think it giving error while serializing childEntities as they are list of the same class.